# Reduce BlueprintJS bundle size

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bundle, blueprintjs, webpack-bundle-analyzer

I'm currently in the process of reducing my bundle size to deploy my project. I've noticed that blueprint takes up a large part of the bundle, approximately 130kb when using Brotli compression:

[image]

Would anyone with experience with BlueprintJS be able to share tips on reducing the size? I love the framework so I would prefer to keep it rather than switch to a smaller alternative.